# jitclass vs extension API : what can be used in a list?

Tags: python, numba

So I did not follow `numba` developments for a while and I discovered a LOT of exciting things, like `@jitclass` and list support.

So I wanted to try it out, but if I try to have a list of my `jitclass` structure in a `nopython` block I get the error :

```
reflected list(instance.jitclass.Interval#42f9788<lo:float64,hi:float64>): unsupported nested memory-managed object
```

With the simple following class

```
@jitclass([('lo', types.float64), ('hi', types.float64)])
class Interval(object):
    def __init__(self, lo, hi):
        self.lo = lo
        self.hi = hi

    @property
    def width(self):
        return self.hi - self.lo
```

And the simplest corresponding code :

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def f(my_list):
    return my_list

f([Interval(1,2)]*10)
```

However if I follow the example of using the lengthy Extension API [here](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/extending/interval-example.html), **I do not get any problem** with having a list of `Interval`.

I thought jitclass was basically a fast way of doing what the lengthy example of the extension API does, am I mistaken? How can one achieve it without having to write these long error prone binding functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually added in Numba 0.39 (http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.39.0/release-notes.html#version-0-39-0)

> List has gained support for containing reference-counted types like NumPy arrays and list. Note, list still cannot hold heterogeneous types.

So now it woks directly.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't completely answer your question, but if you want a quick work-around, I discovered that unlike lists, tuples seem to work:

```
f((Interval(1,2),)*10)
```

gives the output

```
(<numba.jitclass.boxing.Interval at 0x10d8d0d50>,
 <numba.jitclass.boxing.Interval at 0x10d8d0d70>,
 [... clipped ...]
 <numba.jitclass.boxing.Interval at 0x10d8d0e90>)
```

Comment: Good to know indeed. Thanks!